# How to take full height of available viewport for header?

Tags: html, css

Suppose, a Google Chrome window is opened and i want to take full height of visible viewport for header like:[image]

As you can see the blogger website, I want to take visible size of chrome for header. How can i do this?
[image]

Like you can see in the picture. And if possible i dont wanna use vh unit because it shifts header up when i open console in google chrome.

Comment: Like i said i don't want to use vh because the header shifts up while opening console. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery using this code.
The $(window).resize() is useful when you resize the page by using the Chrome console.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('header').height($(window).height());
  
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('header').height($(window).height());
  });
});
```

```css
header {
background: red;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Your header!</header>
```

Comment: Using css vh and jquery is same, isn't it?

Comment: Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```